# Passing Metal buffer to SceneKit shader

Tags: scenekit, metal

I'd like to use a Metal compute shader to calculate some positions that are then fed into a Metal shader. Sounds straight forward, but I'm having trouble getting my MTLBuffer data into the Metal based SCNProgram.

The compute kernel is as follows, in this contrived example it's taking in three 3D vectors (in both buffers).

```
kernel void doSimple(const device float3 *inVector [[ buffer(0) ]],
                    device float3 *outVector [[ buffer(1) ]],
                    uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {

    float yDisplacement = 0;
    . . . .

    outVector[id] = float3(
        inVector[id].x, 
        inVector[id].y + yDisplacement, 
        inVector[id].z);
}
```

This kernel function is run each frame in the `- renderer:willRenderScene:atTime:` method of my `SCNSceneRendererDelegate`.  There's two buffers, and they get switched after each frame.

Buffers are created as follows;

```
func setupBuffers() {
    positions = [vector_float3(0,0,0), vector_float3(1,0,0), vector_float3(2,0,0)]

    let bufferSize = sizeof(vector_float3) * positions.count
    //copy same data into two different buffers for initialisation
    buffer1 = device.newBufferWithBytes(&positions, length: bufferSize, options: .OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
    buffer2 = device.newBufferWithBytes(&positions, length: bufferSize, options: .OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
}
```

And the compute shader is run using the following (in the `willRenderScene` func);

```
    let computeCommandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
    let computeCommandEncoder = computeCommandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()

    computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer1, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
    computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, atIndex: 1)

    computeCommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(numThreadgroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerGroup)
    computeCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
    computeCommandBuffer.commit()
    computeCommandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

    let bufferSize = positions.count*sizeof(vector_float3)
    var data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: buffer2.contents(), length: bufferSize, freeWhenDone: false)
    var resultArray = [vector_float3](count: positions.count, repeatedValue: vector_float3(0,0,0))
    data.getBytes(&resultArray, length:bufferSize)

    for outPos in resultArray {
        print(outPos.x, ", ", outPos.y, ", ", outPos.z)
    }
```

This works, and I can see my compute shader is updating the y coordinate for each vector in the array.

This scene consists of three spheres evenly spaced. The vertex shader simply takes the position calculated in the compute shader and adds it to each vertex position (well the y component anyway). I give each sphere an index, the vertex shader uses this index to pull the appropriate position out of my computed array.

The Metal vertex function is shown below, it's referenced by a `SCNProgram` and set to the material of each sphere.

```
vertex SimpleVertex simpleVertex(SimpleVertexInput in [[ stage_in ]],
                             constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                             constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]],
                             constant MyPositions &myPos [[buffer(2)]],
                             constant uint &index [[buffer(3)]]
                             )
{

    SimpleVertex vert;
    float3 posOffset = myPos.positions[index];
    float3 pos = float3(in.position.x, 
                        in.position.y + posOffset.y, 
                        in.position.z);

    vert.position = scn_node.modelViewProjectionTransform * float4(pos,1.0);

    return vert;
}
```

`MyPositions` is a simple struct containing an array of float3s.

```
struct MyPositions
{
    float3 positions[3];
};
```

I have no problem passing data to the vertex shader using the `setValue` method of each sphere's material as shown below (also done in the `willRenderScene` method). Everything works as expected (the three spheres move upwards).

```
    var i0:UInt32 = 0
    let index0 = NSData(bytes: &i0, length: sizeof(UInt32))
    sphere1Mat.setValue(index0, forKey: "index")
    sphere1Mat.setValue(data, forKey: "myPos")
```

**BUT** this requires the data be copied from the GPU to CPU to GPU and is really something I'd rather avoid. So my question is... **How do I pass a MTLBuffer to a SCNProgram?**

Have tried the following in `willRenderScene` but get nothing but `EXEC_BAD...`

```
let renderCommandEncoder = renderer.currentRenderCommandEncoder!
renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, atIndex: 2)
renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
```

Complete [example is over on GitHub](https://github.com/lachlanhurst/SceneKitMetalBufferTest).

Thanks for reading, been struggling with this one. Workaround is to use a MTLTexture in place of a MTLBuffer as I've been able to pass these into an SCNProgram via the diffuse mat prop.

Comment: Still interested in knowing the answer to this, if it is possible... For the moment I've worked around it by creating a `SCNGeometrySource` backed by a `MTLBuffer` to store my vertex data. The vertex data, as rendered, is then modified by the compute shader directly. There's no custom vertex shader, and hence no need to pass in a `MTLBuffer`.

Answer (score -1):

just switch the bindings of the buffers from step to step.

step1
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer1, offset: 0, atIndex: **0**)
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, atIndex: **1**)

step2
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer1, offset: 0, atIndex: **1**)
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, atIndex: **0**)

step3
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer1, offset: 0, atIndex: **0**)
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, atIndex: **1**)

and so on ...

the out buffer becomes the new in buffer and vice versa ...

Comment: That's what I do for most of my compute functions. But in this case the compute function works fine, the question is about taking the output from a compute shader and passing it into a render function. With SceneKit we have the `SCNProgram` abstraction that supports custom shaders, unfortunately it seems to lack a method to pass in something like a `MTLBuffer`. Would be a complete non-issue if I was using Metal without SceneKit. Thanks

Comment: You wrote in the source code:         
//does not work
        let renderCommandEncoder = renderer.currentRenderCommandEncoder!
        renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(buffer2, offset: 0, atIndex: 2)
        renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
Did you set the two other buffers (0 and 1) also in the renderEncoder? Or  have you done this only for the compute encoder?

I could not try this because I have not the proper iOS hardware. I working with OS X.

Comment: This is worth reviving, as I am going through similar issues. I don't want to loose SceneKit practicalities, but also have some power with metal compute shaders that I would pass along the other buffers. is this not possible ATM? One option I am seeking is to use the compute shader to prepare per fragment color values directly, and pass that through a binding or key/value injection